# How to use key with a dot at the end?

Tags: java, yaml, bukkit

Eg:

```
"This is a sentence.": "This is the result sentence."
```

I got an error that the YAML file becomes an empty path if I put a dot behind the key, how can I solve this?

EDIT:
I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set to an empty path
```

when using this:

```
FileConfiguration langPack_EN = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(getResource("lang_EN.yml"));
```

I was trying to make a language pack, with all translations saved in .yml to be read.

EDIT:
Additional information:
http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#Paths

Example langPack.yml:

```
A:
  B: "Value"
```

Example Code:

```
String test = langPack_EN.get("A"); //Get B as Object
String test2 = langPack_EN.getString("A.B"); //Get "Value" as String
```

Is the dot affecting the 'path'? My assumption.

Comment: Your input is valid as you can test on http://www.yamllint.com/. What do you use to parse it? What exact error do you get?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set to an empty path`
`FileConfiguration langPack_EN = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(getResource("lang_EN.yml"));`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code and error there.

Comment: "Each level is separated by the path separator, which is by default the '.' (period)" So I think your assumtion is correct.

Comment: Is there any escapes for that?

Comment: Ask the developers of the library you use. But why do you want dots in keys?

Comment: As mentioned, I was making a language pack which some of the sentences are with full stops.

Comment: Maybe with a '\' or something like this before the dot...

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the path separator:

```
getConfig().options().pathSeparator(',');
```